# trying to create thumnail layer using jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to use thumbnail part of this gallery http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/
I'm not a very great jquery developer so If any one done that before please help me with it. Regards,
Bin

Comment: What exactly do you want help with? Unless you ask an actual question you're unlikely to get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Awhile back I implemented something similar, except a vertical thumbnail strip. Here is a blog post containing detail about the implementation.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/03/photo-gallery-jquery-film-strip/

Hopefully this will give you some insight in how to proceed.

Bob